# How do I make it possible for my website visitors to upload files and post content?

Tags: jquery, html, phpmyadmin

So, I'm working on an upcoming school project. The web-design is all done and I'm now working on the function mentioned above.

I want to make it possible for my website visitors to upload files and post some content of which I want to be able to review before it's fully published.

I have a xampp setup with phpmyadmin and etc.
But I have no clue how to do it or where to start.

If I could get any help with for example links to guides/articles, or anything else that I will need to read/now to make this function possible, I would be extremly grateful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to file uploading

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiuLBrEFhfk

In regards to reviewing before publishing, I'd create a "review" table in my database and once you reviewed it have a script move the row to your "published" table :)

Comment: Thanks! I now understand how to allow users to upload files. But how do I allow them to post content to the site?

Comment: Your site would have to work in conjunction with your database, i.e it reads from your "published" table and when that table updates so will your site

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a form with an input of type "file" somewhere in your html. When that form is submitted the file that was selected will then be available in the PHP script you have set as the action of the form. A tutorial can be found in the link below

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php